# HTML5 main element versus ARIA landmark role="main"

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm interested to learn more about the relationship, and possible distinctions, between the HTML5 `<main>` element, and the ARIA landmark role attribute `role="main"`.

I'm under the impression that the purpose of the `<main>` element is to map the ARIA roll attribute `role="main"` onto a specific HTML element. But does that sum it up?

Are there benefits to using `<main>` over, say, `<div role="main">`? Or will these, for now and the foreseeable future, yield the same result?

Any insights in comparing the following examples would be greatly appreciated:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  <main>
</body>
```

```
<body>
  <main role="main">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  <main>
</body>
```

```
<body>
  <div role="main">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div>
</body>
```

Comment: Any reason in particular for the bounty? The situation hasn't changed as far as I'm aware; they perform the same action and eventually there will be no need for `role="main"`.

Comment: **See Also**: [Is role="main" necessary on a <main> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22142869/1366033)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to HTML5 Doctor they are equivalent. `<main>` just makes it easier and neater to implement `role="main"`.

> The primary purpose of  is to map ARIA’s landmark role main to an element in HTML.

Here is a general description of the `<main>` element.

> The `main` element represents the main content of the `body` of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

#### Recommendation

It is recommended to use use both `<main>` and `role="main"` in the same element until browsers implement `<main>` properly.

```
<!-- Recommended -->
<main role="main">
    ...
</main>
```

Be sure to read the [`<main>` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) if you're interested.

#### Note on sectioning

As Szabolcs points out in the comments, `<main>` is not a sectioning element so it should be used in conjunction with a `<section>` element.

#### References

- [The main element - HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/)
- [W3C HTML Editors Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'm still curious about any differences between <div role="main"> and <main>, given the current spec. One interesting distinction that I found is that the <main> element is not a block level element - this is easily overlooked when transition from a wrapping div. Thanks again for pointing me to those resources.

Comment: @StuartKershaw Are you sure it's not a block-level element? The Chrome (v30) user agent stylesheet has this rule: `article, aside, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section { display: block; }`. In a non-supporting browser it wouldn't though as I don't think `block` is the default `display`.

Comment: Good catch, it seems Chrome has added <main> to the HTML5 display: block; stack, nice! No love in Firefox yet, it seems.

Comment: Worth noting tho, that according to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element), main is not a sectioning element, so if you want your main to act as section in the outline, you must still use section element with main aria role.

Comment: It may be good practice to ensure all elements, but especially the new ones, are set to their 'default' display setting, as per the current spec. That is, add lines like 'main,article,section,aside,...{display:block}' at the start of your css file.

Comment: @Patanjali I think something like IE 7 or 8 was the last browser you needed to do that for. Which are no longer supported by Microsoft from a few days ago.

Comment: @Daniel Imms. Depends upon your target demographic, some of which may not have a problem with using obsolete software. Even then, it depends upon whether you are prepared to go the extra distance to give graceful failover, or just give the holdouts a sub-standard experience.

Comment: @Patanjali sure it does depend on who you are building the site for. However, obsolete browsers are disasters from a security perspective and anything that can encourage users to move off them is a win imo (unless of course you're being paid to implement said support).

Comment: The w3 validator will actually say `The main role is unnecessary for element main`