# What is role="main" used for in jQuery Mobile 1.4?

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile 1.4 has changed

```
<div data-role="content">...</div>
```

into

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">...</div>
```

I understand the purpose of using a class now instead of a data-role, but what I don't understand is this role="main".  What is it used for?

Comment: It's used in previous versions but added dynamically by JQM.

Comment: I don't see it show up dynamically in the Chrome debugger if I leave it out of the source code.

Comment: If you wrap it in page div, it will be added. Just tested it on 1.3.2

Comment: See this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595719/html5-main-element-and-aria-landmark-role-main

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `role` attribute is native to HTML5 and meant to support WAI-ARIA.
See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#wai-aria and http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions

jQuery Mobile in earlier versions simply transformed elements with the attribute data-role="content" into the main element `<div role="main">` (which is equivalent to `<main>`) and added the CSS.  So you get `<div role="main" class="ui-content">` .

There was no other processing or added markup for elements with data-role="content".  By deprecating the data-role="content" attribute and using ask you to use the correct HTML5 (CSS and WAI-ARIA role) directly, jQuery Mobile will have to do less processing for each page.

Comment: Ah. So shouldn't I use <main class="ui-content">...</main>?

Comment: `role="main"` will be supported by more browsers.  If you use main the spec says you still need the role attribute `<main role="main">`.  Using `<main>` may cause issues with jQuery Mobile's  Single Page Application (SPA) model. Using an SPA model you can get more than one `<main>` element loaded in the DOM as you navigate to different pages.  This is not allowed by the spec.  So while `<div role="main">` is equivalent to `<main>` there are good reasons to use the div instead of the main tag currently.