# Actual effect of using WAI ARIA?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to dig into ARIA and make my websites more accessible.
I understood using ARIA attributes is a good start but I'd like to understand the actual effects of doing so.

If, for instance, I add a role="navigation" on my nav tag used as a menu, what effect will this have for the user?

What will its screenreader (or any app helping him) do?
Is it really useful to add this if I'm already using a nav tag, which obviously is already telling the user that this is a navigation item?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some interesting answers to this question in the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142869/is-role-main-necessary-on-a-main-element

Comment: ARIA us a standard, and the intent is that assistive technology can leverage said standard in a way that suits the particular technology best. In other words, the actual effect on your site is nothing. It's when it's viewed with particular assistive technology that it will be leveraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it is that adding ARIA roles will create a taxonomy of semantics (called landmarks) on your site that a user can navigate to using keyboard shortcuts (key bindings) defined by screen readers with ARIA support.

For example, instead of jumping through actionable elements like buttons/links, the user can use a different key binding to jump to ARIA landmarks instead.

Semantic tags such as "nav" should be handled by the screen reader client by default (and have a specific key binding to do so - usually "tab"). ARIA roles - in this scenario - just add another level of semantics and, by extension, an alternate method for navigating through the page.

A [link to the WAI-ARIA Roles Model W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles).

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and thank you all). I understood the principle, I guess I need to test one of my website with a screen reader to see the result now.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms WAI-ARIA allows developers to talk to the platform accessibility API through HTML mark-up. Platform accessibility API is the way how operating systems expose information about objects on the screen to the assistive technologies.

When you set role="navigation" on an HTML element what happens in the background is, user-agent maps this information to the correct accessibility API on user's operating system. As a result, the assistive technology receives the right semantics about your HTML element.

For example for the "navigation" role user-agent maps this to "AXLandmarkNavigation" on Mac OS X. You can find the full list of mapping of ARAI roles to accessibility APIs on [WAI-ARIA 1.0 User Agent Implementation Guide](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-implementation/#mapping_role_table).